# Show multiple points and lines in Garmin GPS Map

Tags: gps, import, garmin

I have two shapefiles that contain (1) 30 point features and (2) an extensive road network (line features) that connects them.

I would like to show all data at once in the mapview of my Monterra Device to be able to follow the road network and reach the closest waypoints in a given region. I followed all export steps as e.g. indicated here:

http://www.gpszone.ca/blog/2014/03/convert-kml-to-garmin-tutorial/

I successfully imported the waypoints and if I go to the waypoint manager I can see the 30 waypoints one by one. Than I'm able to open a given waypoint by clicking the little map symbol in the edit view.

However for my purpose this is unsatisfying because I want to see all features at once so that I am always able to see the closest waypoints next to me (and later also see the road network to get there). Garmin Software seemed to me quit rudimentary but there should be a way to do that right?

Comment: The number of visible waypoints likely depends on the display settings of the GPS unit. They tend to only show certain things at given zoom levels, and the further out you zoom, the fewer things are drawn. To some degree this can be changed by altering the unit settings to display 'high' detail. In some cases the waypoint itself has properties about when to draw it, or some classes of waypoints can be set to always draw. The road network is an entirely different story, as you're talking about custom base map data.

Comment: thanks chris. the one with altering the unit settings I already tried out but its not satisfying since it only works to a given degree as you indicated (no idea why Garmin limits that). The one with lines I will try with the basecamp software. thx for the hint.